# Difference in Management.ManagementObject between XP and Win7

Tags: c#, windows, vb.net, windows-7, windows-xp

I have two OSes set up, a win7 and an XP, both them are in the same **WORKGROUP** (none of them is in a domain this way)

I'm trying to get the WorkGroup name of the computer with this code:

```
VB.NET:

Public Function GetWorkGroup() As String
    Dim computer_system As New Management.ManagementObject(String.Format("Win32_ComputerSystem.Name='{0}'", Environment.MachineName))
    Dim result As Object = computer_system("Workgroup")
    Return result.ToString()
End Function

C#:

public string GetWorkGroup()
{
    Management.ManagementObject computer_system = new management.ManagementObject(string.Format("Win32_ComputerSystem.Name='{0}'",   Environment.MachineName));
    object result = computer_system("Workgroup");
    return result.ToString();
}
```

This does work on Win7, but on XP computer_system("Workgroup") results in Nothing.
If I want to make it work I have to make the following modification:

```
VB.NET:
        Dim result As Object = computer_system("Domain")
C#:
        object result = computer_system("Domain");
```

This works on both Win7 and XP, gaves back the correct Workgroup name, but cleary somethings wrong if I get back the Workgroup name with the Domain property on XP.

Could someone explain please why does XP handles it's Workgroup as a Domain? thanks.

Comment: also ..are you familiar with WMI.. try looking at examples on using WMI

Comment: @DJKRAZE I know very well what is the difference between domains and workgroups. I'm guessing the question need more clarification: both computers are in a workgroup, thats why i don't get how come on XP this can't return the WG name?